# Why are there white outlines around the subject in this photo when zoomed in?

Tags: artifacts, halos

[image]

Please give me a solution to this if possible. Image showing white outlines when zoomed.

Crop:

[image]

Zoomed:
[image: White outlines and omg my face :(]

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Maybe post a screenshot of the zoomed in image showing the white outline?

Comment: It looks to me like the picture has been heavily sharpened creating halos. Check this out http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-sharpening.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dave Nelson's comment seems to be right: The image is overly sharpened, creating a halo. You do not see it when zoomed out simply because it becomes too small; it is still there.
Look at Dave Nelson's comment for a link to a detailed explanation on digital sharpening.

Edit: Smartphones and even DSLRs typically add digital sharpening themselves. Maybe you have access to the settings of that shaprening.

Comment: I didnt sharpen it. I guess it was the camera app. So is there a solution? I mean to remove those halos

Comment: To solve the problem for future photographs, you can reduce the sharpening in your camera, in most cases, by adjusting a 'picture style' or set of 'parameters'. Check your manual.

Comment: To work with this photo... oh, boy. I'd start with considering a reshoot, but failing that, start by cloning the halo out in Photoshop/GIMP with a very small brush size. You could get fancier, but you're in for a lot of work unless someone here knows a selective blurring trick...

Comment: I have a question - how large is this intended to be printed/viewed? If nobody is going to see this at original size, try scaling it down to the resolution of a 4x6" print (1200px by 1800px @ 300 DPI) and see what you think of it.

Comment: Quick thought: try duplicating the layer, using threshold to capture the range of brightness as close to the halo brightness as possible, and creating a selection from the threshold layer, thus creating a selection fitting the halo of the original photograph. Edit the selection to taste, pop it on the original layer, and blur that halo to your preference. YMMV.

Comment: @TroyR I wish to use it as facebook cover photo

Comment: Try scaling it down and see what comes of it. The reduced size should mask any halos, and if the larger view is still not acceptable, try the idea I mentioned to reduce the halos.